# nn.BCELoss() is giving very bad results unlike BCEWithLogitsLoss

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, cross-entropy

I am trying to build a PyTorch classification program with tabular dataset, my model has the following architecture:

```
BATCH_SIZE = 8 
EPOCHS = 10
HIDDEN_NEURONS = 25
LR = 1e-3

class MyModel(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):

    super(MyModel, self).__init__()

    self.input_layer = nn.Linear(X.shape[1], HIDDEN_NEURONS)
    self.linear = nn.Linear(HIDDEN_NEURONS, 1)
    self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

def forward(self, x):
    x = self.input_layer(x)
    x = self.linear(x)
    x = self.sigmoid(x)

    return x
```

The model is pretty simple and small. The model has the following training loop:

```
total_loss_train_plot = []
total_loss_validation_plot = []
total_acc_train_plot = []
total_acc_validation_plot = []

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    total_acc_train = 0
    total_loss_train = 0
    total_acc_val = 0
    total_loss_val = 0
    ## Training and Validation
    for indx, data in enumerate(train_dataloader):
        input, label = data

        input.to(device)
        label.to(device)

        prediction = model(input).squeeze(1)
        #print(prediction)
        batch_loss = criterion(prediction, label)

        total_loss_train += batch_loss.item()

        acc = ((prediction).round() == label).sum().item()

        total_acc_train += acc

        batch_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()

    ## Validation
    with torch.no_grad():
        for indx, data in enumerate(validation_dataloader):
            input, label = data
            input.to(device)
            label.to(device)

            prediction = model(input).squeeze(1)

            batch_loss = criterion(prediction, label)

            total_loss_train += batch_loss.item()

            acc = ((prediction).round() == label).sum().item()

            total_acc_val += acc

    total_loss_train_plot.append(round(total_loss_train/1000, 4))
    total_loss_validation_plot.append(round(total_loss_val/1000, 4))
    total_acc_train_plot.append(round(total_acc_train/(training_data.__len__())*100, 4))
    total_acc_validation_plot.append(round(total_acc_val/(validation_data.__len__())*100, 4))

    print(f'''Epoch no. {epoch + 1} Train Loss: {total_loss_train/1000:.4f} Train Accuracy: {(total_acc_train/(training_data.__len__())*100):.4f} Validation Loss: {total_loss_val/1000:.4f} Validation Accuracy: {(total_acc_val/(validation_data.__len__())*100):.4f}''')
    print("="*50)
```

The loss and accuracy aren't improving and they are staying constant:

```
Epoch no. 1 Train Loss: 105.9250 Train Accuracy: 44.9603 Validation Loss: 0.0000 Validation Accuracy: 46.4443
==================================================
Epoch no. 2 Train Loss: 105.9250 Train Accuracy: 44.9603 Validation Loss: 0.0000 Validation Accuracy: 46.4443
==================================================
Epoch no. 3 Train Loss: 105.9250 Train Accuracy: 44.9603 Validation Loss: 0.0000 Validation Accuracy: 46.4443
==================================================
Epoch no. 4 Train Loss: 105.8375 Train Accuracy: 44.9603 Validation Loss: 0.0000 Validation Accuracy: 46.4443
==================================================
Epoch no. 5 Train Loss: 105.8375 Train Accuracy: 44.9603 Validation Loss: 0.0000 Validation Accuracy: 46.4443
==================================================
Epoch no. 6 Train Loss: 105.9250 Train Accuracy: 44.9603 Validation Loss: 0.0000 Validation Accuracy: 46.4443
==================================================
Epoch no. 7 Train Loss: 105.9250 Train Accuracy: 44.9603 Validation Loss: 0.0000 Validation Accuracy: 46.4443
==================================================
Epoch no. 8 Train Loss: 105.9250 Train Accuracy: 44.9603 Validation Loss: 0.0000 Validation Accuracy: 46.4443
==================================================
Epoch no. 9 Train Loss: 105.9250 Train Accuracy: 44.9603 Validation Loss: 0.0000 Validation Accuracy: 46.4443
==================================================
Epoch no. 10 Train Loss: 105.8375 Train Accuracy: 44.9603 Validation Loss: 0.0000 Validation Accuracy: 46.4443
==================================================
```

But when I changed the loss to `BCEWithLogitsLoss` and removed the sigmoid layer, the training improved and worked fine by reducing loss and increasing the accuracy. When I change the loss to the loss with logits I get these results:

```
Epoch no. 1 Train Loss: 0.7597 Train Accuracy: 96.7476 Validation Loss: 0.0000 Validation Accuracy: 98.8270
==================================================
Epoch no. 2 Train Loss: 0.9141 Train Accuracy: 96.2841 Validation Loss: 0.0000 Validation Accuracy: 98.6070
==================================================
Epoch no. 3 Train Loss: 0.6364 Train Accuracy: 97.2189 Validation Loss: 0.0000 Validation Accuracy: 98.1305
==================================================
Epoch no. 4 Train Loss: 0.7539 Train Accuracy: 96.5748 Validation Loss: 0.0000 Validation Accuracy: 98.8270
==================================================
Epoch no. 5 Train Loss: 0.8025 Train Accuracy: 96.6062 Validation Loss: 0.0000 Validation Accuracy: 96.8109
==================================================
Epoch no. 6 Train Loss: 0.6069 Train Accuracy: 96.8340 Validation Loss: 0.0000 Validation Accuracy: 98.9370
==================================================
Epoch no. 7 Train Loss: 0.6626 Train Accuracy: 96.8261 Validation Loss: 0.0000 Validation Accuracy: 96.2977
==================================================
Epoch no. 8 Train Loss: 0.5833 Train Accuracy: 96.6140 Validation Loss: 0.0000 Validation Accuracy: 98.6804
==================================================
Epoch no. 9 Train Loss: 0.4303 Train Accuracy: 97.3604 Validation Loss: 0.0000 Validation Accuracy: 98.2405
==================================================
Epoch no. 10 Train Loss: 0.5376 Train Accuracy: 97.0225 Validation Loss: 0.0000 Validation Accuracy: 96.9208
==================================================
```

I know the difference between the two functions. One of them accepts only probabilities (`BCELoss`) after the sigmoid and the other with the logits before the sigmoid. But why the network behave like this on changing both functions ? I used to do Bert for binary text classification with `BCELoss` and worked perfectly fine.
Any explaination on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I had to normalize my data. I normalized the data using the following code and worked very fine:

```
for column in data_df.columns:
    data_df[column] = data_df[column]/data_df[column].abs().max()
data_df.head()
```